# Iterating over range and indexing in array in groovy

Tags: groovy

With more use of groovy, I feel a bit un comformtable to write `for(){}` loops. Almost always I avoid Java `for(){}` loop and go for groovy `each{}` loop. However there is one case when I cannot avoid `for(){}`.

In our project, we do not return iterator to the list which is a member of a certain class. We return size of list and then get(index) method as can be seen in below excerpt:

```
class ClassWithList
{
    private def tempList = ["a","b","c"]

    public int getNumberOfItems()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    public String getItem(int pIndex)
    {
    return tempList[pIndex];
    }
}
```

The calling class first calls `getNumberOfItems()` and then uses `getItem()` to iterate over list:

```
ClassWithList obj = new ClassWithList();
for(int i=0;i<obj.getNumberOfItems();i++)
    println obj.getItem(i)
```

With `each{}`, this takes following form:

```
ClassWithList obj = new ClassWithList();
(0..obj.getNumberOfItems()-1).each {
    println obj.getItem(it)
}
```

The issue occurs when their is no element in the list, in which case the range will be `(0..-1)`. It down counts and result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when attempt is made to read an item at negative index of `-1`. For example below code results in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
class AdHocTests {
    public static main(def args)
    {   
        ClassWithList obj = new ClassWithList();
        (0..obj.getNumberOfItems()-1).each {
            println obj.getItem(it)
        }
    }   
}

class ClassWithList
{
    private def tempList = []

    public int getNumberOfItems()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public String getItem(int pIndex)
    {
    return tempList[pIndex];
    }
}
```

How can I get `(0..x).each{}()` work with `x=0` in such scenario? Or there is no way out, and I should just stick to traditional `for(){}`. Does groovy offers something for surprise?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Ranges), you can use a half-opened range:

```
(0..<obj.getNumberOfItems()).each {
    println obj.getItem(it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in Groovy you don't need to specify private attribute because it is made by default. Moreover, getters and setters are created by default too, so you only have to call them.

If I have understood your question, you only want to iterate in the list.

Cleaning your class will be:

class ClassWithList{

```
List tempList = ["a","b","c"]
```

}

//In order to iterate the list, you only need the each method:

```
ClassWithList obj = new ClassWithList()  //; Not necessary in groovy!!
(obj.tempList).each { def element ->
    println element
}
```

The answer will be: [a, b, c]

Hope to  help you